# If File = "False" Application.GetOpenFileName Error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to ensure `Application.GetOpenFileName` doesn't break if someone hits cancel when selecting a file.

I have an if statement that states if file = "false" then show a msgbox and exit sub.
This works when no file is selected, however when I run the macro with the files selected I get a Type Mismatch error.

```vb
Dim nom As String
Dim wb1, wb2, wb3, wb4, wb5 As Excel.Workbook
Dim i, j, k, file As Variant

nom = ActiveWorkbook.Name
If CurDir() <> CurDir("J:") Then
    ChDrive "J:"
    ChDir "J:FEA Material Data"
End If
For i = 1 To 5
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MsgBox ("Select Compound" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If Data From Criterion, Select Loading Only" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If Data From Alliance, Select All")
    file = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
      FileFilter:="Text Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
      MultiSelect:=True)
    If file = "False" Then
        MsgBox "No File Selected"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        counter = 1
        While counter <= UBound(file)
            Workbooks.Open file(counter)
            counter = counter + 1
        Wend
    End If 
    'more code
```

Comment: `if not isarray(file) then if file = "false" exit sub`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it has files it returns a variant with an array. `Debug.Print VarType(file)` returns 8204. So you need to check the array for file names. If the user selects Cancel then the Variant will be a boolean.

```
If VarType(file) = 11 Then
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
    Exit Sub
```

Or more readable (thanks to Dirk Reichel):

```
If Not IsArray(file) Then
    MsgBox "No File Selected"
    Exit Sub
```

[Determining the Type of a Variant](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Data-Type/DeterminingtheTypeofaVariant.htm)

Comment: Not sure if you need a msgbox if the user clicked Cancel. Isn't their intent obvious? "Of course I didn't select a file, I didn't want to."

Comment: would not `isarray` be the easier to understand option? (in this case, cus it is all he need to know)

Comment: Sure. But the OP was trying to check for a cancel so I have it checking for a boolean. Either works fine although admittedly mine isn't very readable.

Comment: I'm not sure if that works... it was more a question... will selecting just one file still be an array (having just one item)?

Comment: Always an array if `MultiSelect:=True`

Comment: If `MultiSelect:=False` then just compare `If file = False Then` works well.

Comment: Thanks guys, This fixed the problem

Comment: @D_Bester Wanted to note for anyone that was dumb like I was and used `Dim file As String`, if you use `MultiSelect:=False`, and do `If file = False Then Exit Sub`, you get a type mismatch. If you use the `If Not IsArray(file) Then Exit Sub` line, it just always ends, even though it has a file path in it. If you use `If VarType(file) = 11 Then Exit Sub`, it will always let it go on to the next lines, even if they clicked Cancel. It was driving me NUTS. It wasn't until I checked another forum I realized: you have to make `file` a `Variant` type for it to work. :ugh:

Answer (score -2):

**Single File Selection Mode**

If you were doing `MultiSelect:=False`, where you have:

```
If file = "False" Then
```

it should be:

```
If file = False Then
```

- The variant returns a Boolean value if <kbd>Cancel</kbd> is selected, not a `False` as a String value. Once corrected to not use quotes, it would exit on <kbd>Cancel</kbd>.
- If a file path exists, there is no type mismatch when comparing the Boolean value against the String, and it would fall into your `Else` condition if there *was* a value, since it won't be `False`, just like we would want.

**BUT**....

**Multi-File Selection Mode**

Since you're doing `MultiSelect:=True` -- even if you corrected it to use

```
If file = False Then
```

it will NOT work like the above and it would give you a mismatch error if it actually DOES have something, because it would be comparing a Boolean value you're supplying in the condition statement against an Array that is coming back.

```
If Not IsArray(file) Then
```

as @D_Bester and @Dirk Reichel gave you is best in this case.

I'm not just writing this to take credit for their answer, however, as I wanted to explain everything in more depth, because there are multiple facets to this than to just say "use that" and it can get confusing, and it was maddening me for a bit, too, so I felt we should have the reasons spelled out in a fuller answer:

- This works because it will ALSO return the `False` value (like in the Single File Selection Mode) if <kbd>Cancel</kbd> is selected, and the Boolean value will be tested for being an Array object, found to obviously not be an Array, and will exit. (This is beneficial because we need an array of file names to proceed: no array? Exit.)
- The reason you cannot just test for `False` all the time (both modes) and get away with it is because, if the dialog result actually DOES have a value, it will now be an Array of file paths. A type mismatch comparison of a Boolean `False` against an Array of file paths would result.
- Similarly, you cannot just always test for an Array of file paths (for ex. `If UBound(file) = 0 Then`) either, because, as previously noted in my first bullet, it will return the Boolean instead of an Array when the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button is clicked and give you a type mismatch when trying to get the length of the Boolean object, because there are no underlying slots in a Boolean.

Comment: To be clear: all users are free to vote how they feel and under no obligation to post any comments in any circumstances.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr